# Get warnings when installing joomla

Tags: joomla

I want to learn how to work with Joomla, but I'm stuck at a very first step - installing Joomla. I'm trying to install Joomla using Filezilla. And when I go to my website after I uploaded joomla, I get warnings like this:

[image: errors]

What do I do, guys?

Comment: Please put the warning in text and also tell us what you found when you googled it.  Also I'm really not sure what you mean by "install using Filezilla."  Are you uploading a local install that works without the messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all warning from administration panel of joomla:

1) In admin Panel, find Global configuration tab and click then Go to Error reporting and select none option after that refresh your page then you will not find any warning.

Comment: uploading files with SmartFTP solved the problem. Don't know what's wrong with FileZilla...

Comment: Why did you write this as a comment of this answer ?